# Xamarin Analog Clock rotate handle by following finger gesture

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, gesture-recognition

I have a task to move the analog clock handle by following finger movements and simultaneously updating the clock value in text box. Is it possible in Xamarin.Forms or have to go with Xamarin.Android?

Comment: I'd consider using SkiaSharp for this

Comment: If you want to do in Xamarin.forms ,you can try to use custome renderers .However is related to Android.Also can do in IOS.You can refer to this:https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/AnalogClock/